# What is the coefficient of kinetic friction between wood and glass?

Tags: friction

I've seen values online for the coefficient of kinetic friction for wood on wood (0.2) as well as glass on glass (0.4), but can't seem to find the value for wood on glass.

Comment: Have you  checked the Engineering Toolbox site?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, hard to find references. Nerveless, [this](https://publications.drdo.gov.in/ojs/index.php/dsj/article/download/7531/4215/0) gives static friction coefficient wood/glass around $0.13-0.14$, so for kinetic friction coefficient reduce down that value for about 25%. But [this](https://studylib.net/doc/18691304/friction-of-wood-sliding-on-various-materials) gives it as $0.2$. So summing up results seems that kinetic friction coefficient is in range $0.1-0.2$.